# I want to remove all the brackets value

Tags: sh

I want to remove all the brackets value from first column in linux

```
Eg:
EXAMPLE(abc@gmail.com),60,6
EXAMPLE(bcd@gmail.com),30,6
EXAMPLE1(sample@gmail.com),60,3

Required Output :

EXAMPLE,60,6
EXAMPLE,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
```

Below is code which I tried but no luck :

```
for file_name in tmpy/*.csv
do
   awk -F '[,(]' -v OFS=',' '{first = $2; $2=""; print $0}' $file_name > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv $file_name
done
```

So please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: `sed 's/([^)]*)//g'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/[(].*[)]/,"")}1' file

EXAMPLE,60,6
EXAMPLE,30,6
EXAMPLE1,60,3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help